# How to close a file in C# that was opened with Process.Start

Tags: c#

I have files in a folder that have been encrypted and need to be opened with notepad in order to be decrypted. In my program I'm opening the files using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path\filename.extension.extenstion");
```

This works perfectly for opening the individual files in Notepad. What I want to do is close the notepad application after it opens. Is there a way to kill the process or close the app window in C#? Or perhaps simply close all Notepad windows once all of the files have been opened and decrypted?

Comment: You can use `.Kill()` to shut down a process.

Comment: *"need to be opened with notepad in order to be decrypted"* Why?

Comment: "files ... need to be opened with notepad in order to be decrypted." Why?

Comment: How does opening the file in Notepad decrypt it? Are you referring to Window's built in file encryption? That's done transparently to the system. Opening it in your application will work.

Comment: Are you storing the processes in a collection, or is there just the one instance of it?

Comment: I think @kdejarnet's decrypting the file before opening with notepad, then wants to delete the decrypted temp file as soon as notepad's closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by decrypting and stuff, but to kill a process, you use `Process.Kill()`. So your code would look like:

```
Process proc = Process.Start(filename);
// do stuff
proc.Kill();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.kill()` function.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
void myprocess()
{
    Process myproc = Process.Start(...);
    Process notepad =  Process.Start(NOTEPAD.EXE)
    //do whatever
    notepad.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: Thanks Cole and Joe. To the questions regarding the decryption it's a very old decryption program used by the state agency that encrypts the files to be downloaded and it's programmed to be opened with Notepad.

Comment: @kdejarnet *".... and it's programmed to be opened with Notepad."* What does it mean? It doesn't make any sense. Ask your **real** problem, not your belief.

Comment: @QtX Please stop being a keyboad tough guy. Cole and Joe gave me the answer I need and I will test it tomorrow. If you can't understand that an old, very old, program has been designed to use Notepad to decrypt a file there really isn't anything I can tell you to help you understand. Please refrain from further comments if you don't have anything constructive to add. Thanks.